# Why BottomSheetBehavior throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal state argument: 2 when I'm trying to set state to STATE_SETTLING

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I have a method which take action against map click, when i click on map, method trying to set the state to `STATE_SETTLING` but it's throwing `IllegalArgumentException`

I have checked the state if it's not in `STATE_HIDDEN` or `STATE_SETTLING` & `isHideable` is `true`, but it's throwing `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal state argument: 2`
. I have tried to set the state to `STATE_EXPANDED`, `STATE_HALF_EXPENDED`, those state are working well, but not that i want.

```
fun onMapClickListener(zonesViewModel: ZonesViewModel){
    if(zonesViewModel.merchantInfoBottomLayout!!.state != BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN || zonesViewModel.merchantInfoBottomLayout!!.state != BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING){
        zonesViewModel.merchantInfoBottomLayout!!.isHideable = true
        zonesViewModel.merchantInfoBottomLayout!!.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING
    }

    }
}
```

Crash logs:

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal state argument: 2
        at android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior.startSettlingAnimation(BottomSheetBehavior.java:755)
        at android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.java:650)
        at *.*.*.*.*.*.*.MerchantsZoneLocationHandler.onMapClickListener(MerchantsZoneLocationHandler.kt:171)
        at *.*.*.*.*.*.*.ZonesFragment$setupMerchantsComponents$2.onMapClick(ZonesFragment.kt:119)
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapGestureDetector.notifyOnMapClickListeners(MapGestureDetector.java:882)
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapGestureDetector$StandardGestureListener.onSingleTapConfirmed(MapGestureDetector.java:327)
        at com.mapbox.android.gestures.StandardGestureDetector$1.onSingleTapConfirmed(StandardGestureDetector.java:81)
        at android.view.GestureDetector$GestureHandler.handleMessage(GestureDetector.java:300)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is solved, I needed to change my code a little bit, while I was trying to set state to `STATE_SETTLING` it's throwing `IllegalArgumentException`, I've just changed my code to:

```
zonesViewModel.merchantInfoBottomLayout!!.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED
```

instead of

```
zonesViewModel.merchantInfoBottomLayout!!.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING`
```